# How to create vertex at the middle of a group?

Tags: modeling, vertices, vertex-groups

I am currently working on a model of a cute little microbe with these little green hair things coming out.  Currently, the hair object ends with a ring of vertices, but I want to create a single vertex connected to all of the outside vertices, like how a UV sphere is when it is created.  How do I do that?

The first image is the hair object currently, second is a newly created UV sphere.
[image: The hair object, with a ring of vertices at the end]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the face selected, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and select *Poke Faces*

[image: Poke1]

Alternatively, you can inset the face with <kbd>I</kbd> and then press <kbd>M</kbd> (Merge), and select *At Center*.

[image: Poke2]

Same result either way:

[image: Poke3]